# L5.1 Class App\Console\Kernel does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

whenever im trying to run `composer update` or `require`, or `php artisan` - i get error

```
root@websites:/var/www/rafdev.ovh/html/msvixen# composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
> php artisan clear-compiled
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class App\Console\Kernel does not exist' in /var/www/rafdev.ovh/html/msvixen/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:737
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/rafdev.ovh/html/msvixen/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(737): ReflectionClass->__construct('App\Console\Ker...')
#1 /var/www/rafdev.ovh/html/msvixen/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(627): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('App\Console\Ker...', Array)
#2 /var/www/rafdev.ovh/html/msvixen/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(674): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('App\Console\Ker...', Array)
#3 /var/www/rafdev.ovh/html/msvixen/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(216): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('App\Console\Ker...', Array)
#4 /var/www/rafdev.ovh/html/msvixen/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(734): Illuminate\Container\Cont in /var/www/rafdev.ovh/html/msvixen/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 737
Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-update-cmd event returned with an error



  [RuntimeException]                                                                                                                                                        
  Error Output: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class App\Console\Kernel does not exist' in /var/www/rafdev.ovh/html/msvixen/vend  
  or/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:737                                                                                                           
  Stack trace:                                                                                                                                                              
  #0 /var/www/rafdev.ovh/html/msvixen/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(737): ReflectionClass->__construct('App\Console\Ker...')              
  #1 /var/www/rafdev.ovh/html/msvixen/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(627): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('App\Console\Ker...', Ar  
  ray)                                                                                                                                                                      
  #2 /var/www/rafdev.ovh/html/msvixen/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(674): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('App\Console\Ker...',   
  Array)                                                                                                                                                                    
  #3 /var/www/rafdev.ovh/html/msvixen/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(216): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('App\Console\Ker...',   
  Array)                                                                                                                                                                    
  #4 /var/www/rafdev.ovh/html/msvixen/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(734): Illuminate\Container\Cont in /var/www/rafdev.ovh/html/msvixen/  
  vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 737                                                                                               



update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--with-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [--] [<packages>]...


root@websites:/var/www/rafdev.ovh/html/msvixen#
```

and this is my `composer.json` file

```
    {
      "name": "laravel/laravel",
      "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
      "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
      ],
      "license": "MIT",
      "type": "project",
      "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
        "skmetaly/laravel-twitch-restful-api": "dev-master",
        "laravelcollective/html": "5.*"
      },
      "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1"
      },
      "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
          "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
          "App\\": "app/"
        }
      },
      "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
          "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
      },
      "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
          "php artisan clear-compiled",
          "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "pre-update-cmd": [

        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
          "php artisan clear-compiled",
          "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
          "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
          "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
      },
      "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
      }
    }
```

Comment: Does your `app/Console/Kernel.php` file exist?

Comment: yes @ceejayoz it does, that error started to popup after i tried to get laravelcollective package to get `HTML` and `FORM` classes work.

Comment: Did you try removing the laravelcollective dependancy? What is the namespace definition in `app/Console/Kernel.php`?

Comment: I tried by `composer remove` manualy in `composer.json` and in `vendor/` directory. No success. I think it might some thing with cache. Namespace: `namespace App\Console;`

Comment: Still the same error. It appears after `php artisan clear-compiled` command is called. Packages downloaded successfully but that error makes my website not working at all.

Answer (score 6):

To better understand this (succinctly): Compiled.php has what amounts to a snapshot map of your existing application. A composer update has the ability to change the location or existence of classes mapped in the snapshot. When this happens, compiled.php can't find the classes in its map. (This is why 'clear-compiled' should *almost* always be run in the pre-update-cmd block.)

This problem generally happens during upgrades or abnormal file-system changes that essentially invalidate compiled.php. The good news is that there is a way around this.

If it is just your compiled.php that is messed up, you can manually delete it and try the composer update again. This is normally done with "php artisan clear-compiled" but since artisan uses compiled.php, this command blocks itself. Hence the need to manually remove the compiled.php file.

```
$ rm bootstrap/cache/compiled.php
$ composer update
```

If you still get errors about missing classes, it means there's something missing in your filesystem that is expected elsewhere. This next part is a little tricky, but it works.

Based on what I'm looking at in your composer.json file, you will likely need to move the "php artisan clear-compiled" command from the 'post-update-cmd' to the 'pre-update-cmd' block. This way the compiled.php file doesn't block artisan as described above after composer updates your files.

The full process for de-funking this situation is:

1. Manually delete compiled.php (usually in /bootstrap/cache for L5.1)
2. Make sure no artisan commands are run in the "pre-update-cmd" block of your composer.json (for you specifically, this is not a problem)
3. Run composer update
4. Put back any removed artisan commands in the "pre-update-cmd" block of your composer.json (for you specifically, just move clear-compiled from post to pre)

If you have continued issues, please comment.

Comment: To better understand this (succinctly): Compiled.php has what amounts to a snapshot map of your existing application. A composer update has the ability to change the location or existence of classes mapped in the snapshot. When this happens, compiled.php can't find the classes in its map. This is why 'clear-compiled' should always be run in the pre-update-cmd block.

Comment: I suggest you update your answer with the above comment, as it is relevant.

Comment: Comment added to answer.

Comment: There's no `compiled.php` in `bootstrap/cache` directory. Thank you for this comment tho!

Comment: It looks like my answer won't fix your exact problem, but I'm still curious about it. Are you running a 'workbench' of some kind on this project? What else updated when you ran the original 'composer update' to bring in the Laravel Collective package?

Comment: It might not work, but it's worth a shot to try a simple: "composer dump-autoload". It looks like autoload should be fine since the composer part of your update apparently worked just fine.

Comment: @Trip What do you mean by 'workbench' ? When i ran `composer update` from what i remember only Laravel Collective package pulled in. And `composer dump-autoload` aswell as `composer clearcache` doesn't do anything to fix it ;s

Comment: 'Workbench' was something that was built into L4 but requires an add-on for L5. It is used for package development and allows you to install multiple versions of packages (one for main application's composer.json, and one for dev package's composer.json; not intended as a 'feature') which can frequently lead to bugs like this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with namespaces. I didn't even realize it was it, I used `php artisan app:name myname` before, and it updated files, but it didn't update `composer.json` file. So I reverted every file that it changed namespace in - and now it works.

Silly but how time consuming...

Comment: fixed the namespaces but still getting the error, then i deleted the vendor folder and downloaded it again with `composer install` now works

Comment: @LeandroRR Yes removing `vendor` folder and redo `composer install` worked for me.