# Laravel: Class App\Console\Commands\BlockModelsDidNotShowUp does not exist

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to run `composer update` on my project on a production server and I keep getting this error:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postUpdate
> php artisan optimize


  [ReflectionException]
  Class App\Console\Commands\BlockModelsDidNotShowUp does not exist


Script php artisan optimize handling the post-update-cmd event returned with error code 1
```

Before this I had a *permission denied* error because of `/storage/logs/laravel.log file` - I've updated permissions on that file and I keep getting an error from above.

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33761186/l5-1-class-app-console-kernel-does-not-exist), but I don't have `bootstrap/cache/compiled.php` file.

Comment: Try `composer dump-autoload` and re-run; might solve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you deleted this class, just clear the cache with:

```
php artisan clear-compiled
```

Or delete `bootstrap/cache/services.php` file manually.